# Highlit rows based on cell date with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, conditional-statements

I have an excel worksheet where I store employees details (name, age etc. ). On column G I have their insurance expiry date stored. Is there a way to change the whole employee row cells color, font color and make the font bold if the expiry date in column G is 3,2,1 days away from expiring. I tryed with conditional formating but doesn`t work as there are many people that use this workbook and they keep using copy/paste and deleting rows when employees no longer work and the format condition keep getting messed up.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
sub test()
dim i as integer
dim k as integer
dim start as range
set start = sheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
k = change of rows between the expiry date and the cell you want to make bold

for i = 0 to End 'How many rows you need to check
  if start.offset(i, 0) < today() then 'Not sure if today is a vba formula but you can adjust the if statement to your purpose. 
     start.offset(i, x).forecolor = Bold ' This is not the correct way of making text bold, but you could google that yourself. 
end if
next i
end sub
```

This is a very rough start to make what you are looking for. If you need to make more than 1 cell bold, either insert another loop, or use ranges instead of the offset that I use above.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I basicaly do not understant a thing from this code :). Seems that I have a lot to learn. I will google it and maybe find some tutorials or something. thanks again for your reply! Have a great day

Comment: Instead of code, i'll try with text: 
Loop through the column with the expiry date, create an if statement and check if that cell is 3 days more than todays day. if this is true, make row bold, if not, then nothing. 
then check the next cell